# C# Handling Message Class IPM.Outlook.Recall

Tags: c#, outlook, console-application, outlook-2016

I have a console application using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook reference that iterates through mailitems in a set of shared inboxes and saves the message fields to a database, the message to a specific file path for reference in a workflow application, then moves the emails to a subfolder. The problem I am encountering is when the sender recalls a message (MessageClass = "IPM.Outlook.Recall"). The program stops because it is waiting on me to click "OK" in Outlook. How do I get my console app to programmatically execute the button "OK" click in Outlook, so the program can move on to the next email?

I have done extensive searches for 3 days for a solution to this problem with no luck. This is in Windows 10, Outlook 2016.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (Object itm in inbox.Items)
            {
                if (itm is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    //Select Email messages from Inbox
                    Outlook.MailItem msg = (Outlook.MailItem)itm;
                    if (msg.MessageClass == "IPM.Outlook.Recall")
                    { 
                         ///Solution for handling recall?
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Extract fields from email
                        EmailMessageFields emailFields = new EmailMessageFields();
                        emailFields.Source = workflow;
                        emailFields.MessageFields(msg);
                        string checkSender = SenderCheck(msg, job);
                        if (checkSender == "")
                        {
                            bool saveSuccess = SaveEmailMessage(msg, boxName, emailFields.ConversationIx);
                            if (!saveSuccess)
                            {
                                msg.Move(loadError);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Check if email already uploaded then flag as duplicate and move if true
                                bool dupeCheck = CheckDuplicates(emailFields.ConversationIx);
                                if (dupeCheck == true)
                                {
                                    msg.Move(wsco);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Insert extracted fields into Email table
                                    bool results = InsertMessageFields(emailFields);
                                    if (results)
                                    {
                                        //Move Email to subfolder
                                        msg.Move(wsco);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //If unable to save, move to Load Errors folder
                                        msg.Move(loadError);
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (checkSender == "Not Loaded")
                            {
                                msg.Move(notloaded);
                            }
                            else if (checkSender == "Faxes")
                            {
                                Outlook.MAPIFolder faxFolder = wsco.Folders["Faxes"];
                                msg.Move(faxFolder);
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (itm is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                {
                    Outlook.AppointmentItem aitem = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)itm;
                    aitem.Move(notloaded);
                }
                else if (itm is Outlook.ReportItem)
                {
                    //Check if email is mail item or return system message
                    Outlook.ReportItem ritem = (Outlook.ReportItem)itm;
                    ritem.Move(notloaded);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my question on MSDN Forums. Instead of trying to process the recall, I decided to skip over it by adding the Restrict method. My updated code is:

```
 foreach (Object itm in inbox.Items.Restrict("[MessageClass] = 'IPM.Note'"))
                    {
                        if (itm is Outlook.MailItem)
                        {
                            //Select Email messages from Inbox
                            Outlook.MailItem msg = (Outlook.MailItem)itm;

                              .......
```